# How can I use the "typing effect" CSS animation here in conjunction with Bootstrap's responsiveness?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, animation

There is a nice typing animation I would like to use on my personal website:
https://codepen.io/rusjames/pen/uAFhE

However, when I try to put it inside a `jumbotron` in bootstrap, I notice that it does not respond to the window resizing (e.g. making the window smaller makes it fall offscreen) that normal text would.

Is there a way I can have this text respond to the window size, and all the other nice properties of bootstrap?

EDIT: The CSS is exactly the same as the link about, except I changed it from applying to all `p` to a class called `typing`:

```
    <div id="main" class="container-fluid text-center push-center">
    <div style="background:transparent !important" class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Welcome to my site</h1>
        <p class="typing"> <i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            I am from America </p>
            <p class="typing"> <i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                I love to work. </p> 
                <p class="typing"> 
                    Contact me! <span>|</span>
                </p>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: where is the code for your jumbotron with the typing code?

Comment: Yes, though you need to right a few media queries to adjust the animation and the elements used, as they don't scale normally being meant to not break line within the 2 `p` elements

Comment: I've updated my post with the code. I have no concept of media queries. I changed the CSS from applying to all `p` to a class I called `typing`. Does this change anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by specifying `font-size` in viewport units, as seen here:
[Scaling font size with screen size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37707705/scaling-font-size-with-screen-size/37707751#37707751)

This applies to all kinds of text.

Comment: This worked, thank you. Is there any reason this would not work in the `.typing {}` CSS class I created? It seems to only work when I use it in the `.typing:nth-child{}` class.

Comment: @AlwaysQuestioning It depends on the precedence of other CSS rules. Try `p.typing {}`

Comment: That worked as well! And for my last question -- do you know where in this code is making the text scroll across the screen? I was hoping to get the typing effect from a static position in the center of my screen.

Comment: @AlwaysQuestioning Try `margin:0 auto` on `p.typing`

Comment: That placed it in the center, but they still scroll to the right. I did some trial and error and it seems like it has to do with `width: 60em`. It's tricky because if I remove this, then the animation part goes away entirely. So I'm not sure why the animation is tied to it scrolling to the right after it's been typed.

Comment: @AlwaysQuestioning Yes, that is because the animation needs fixed width to work... Kinda crappy in my opinion.

Comment: It is probably better to use Javascript + CSS for this. Something that splits the entire string into separate elements for each character. That will allow much more flexibility.